# Excel Lookup Where another Column has Value

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am attempting to create a macro in excel vba that performs the following functions.  We have a list of transactions, and the same customer can have multiple transactions.

However, the Customer's ID, which is required, is not always listed.  For Example, Say Column 'A' has the customer names and 'B' has the IDs.  If Column 'B' is blank for a particular instance I want to find the next instance of Column 'B' under the same Customer Name that has value, and put that value into all of the Column 'B's (I could also do this line by line).

I have considered using a vlookup, but the columns are unordered and I cannot find how to add a "Vlookup where XXX".

Thanks.
I cannot embed an image yet, so here is a link to how the sheet may be formatted.
[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx8m7.png)

I am looking have the same numbers for each of the names in VBA.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use an embedded `If` statement. I can't give you the exact statement because you've not posted any code or what you've tried. To illustrate your situation, you would use a statement similar to:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),C3,B3)
```

Then embed this into your `VLOOKUP` like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(ISBLANK(B3),C3,B3),Sheet2!A1:G132,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  Unfortunately, as much as I understand it, wouldn't this code 1)Determine if B is blank, using C if it is.  Then Search the sheet for an exact match of Column C?  As of now I am fixing it up by sorting it and guaranteeing that one instance for each Name has a number and moving from there.

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail on your problem, including what you've tried and the errors you get, in order for anyone to provide more detailed and correct help.